# PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats range from 1 workbbok to another - Removed Feature: Conditional formatting from

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range with conditional formatting (if cell contains b, then blue, if r the red.....). I wrote a code to copy this range to another workbook with

```
templateWorkbook.Worksheets("CARNET").Range(strCellToStartTCoy).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
templateWorkbook.Worksheets("CARNET").Range(strCellToStartTCoy).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

When I try to open file (already in win explorer, clicking on the file, in the preview, I see "The file cant be previewed because of an eror.....) I get

We found a problem with some content in "....xlsx. Do you want to try to recover as much as we can, Yes or No, I click on Yes , I get

Removed Feature: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

and workbook opens with values copied but not the conditional formatting

licking on the err log xml file I see the same message but it is not very useful
[image]

Of course, when I do it manually, it works fine between the 2 workbooks

Comment: What are the conditional formatting rules being copied and do they refer to ranges in the original workbook?

Comment: Yes it is copying a range from 1st workbook to the 2nd, It is coloring the cell based on a letter, b, v,... cell value begins wit r = =$C$460:$D$469;$C$453:$D$458;$C$439:$D$445;$C$435:$D$437;$C$431:$D$433;$C$425:$D$427;$C$418:$D$423;$C$408:$D$416;$C$403:$D$406;$C$399:$D$401;$C$396:$D$397;$C$392:$D$394;$C$337:$D$342;$C$333:$D$335;$C$327:$D$331;$C$316:$D$320;$C$262:$D$281;$C$253:$D$258;$C$239:$D$251;$C$235:$D$237;$C$232:$D$233;$C$227:$D$230;$C$221:$D$225;$C$215:$D$219........................................ then for b same thing